# What's the difference between Seq.toList and List.ofSeq?

Tags: f#

I was reading [Choosing between collection functions](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/) on the fsharpforfunandprofit site, and he showed an example of how to avoid accessing a disposable resource after it had been disposed (Section 28, right at the end of the article).

He simulated a database with the following...

```
let dbConnection() =
  printfn "Opening connection"
  { new System.IDisposable with
    member this.Dispose() =
      printfn "Disposing connection"
  }

// Read some records from the database
let readCustomersFromDb conn n =
  let makeCustomer i =
    sprintf "Customer %d" i
  seq {
    for i = 1 to n do
      let customer = makeCustomer i
      printfn "Loading %s from the database" customer
      yield customer
  }
```

...and then showed how to avoid the problem by enumerating the sequence before returning it...

```
let readCustomers() =
  use conn = dbConnection()
  let results = readCustomersFromDb conn 2
  results |> List.ofSeq
```

I was a bit confused by that last bit, as I thought we had a sequence, and wanted to convert it to a list. This is how it works in C#, which could be where I'm thinking wrongly. He seems to be taking a list and converting it to a sequence.

Anyway, I tried changing that last line to...

```
  results |> Seq.toList
```

...and it worked just the same.

So, what's the difference between the two, and why do they do the same thing here? I thought sequences were non-enumerated, in which case I would have expected his original code not to have worked.

Comment: both converts a seq into a list - so of course they will enumerate all of your elements

Comment: `List.ofSeq` is creating a List from a sequence and `Seq.toList` does the same.  There is no real difference between them.

Comment: @JohnPalmer To bad SO doesn't let the OP select a comment as the correct answer.

Comment: indeed they **are the same** - see [here (line 571)](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/8f02ecb0b79947e67e6a0ef9c482d167baf17696/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs) : `let ofSeq source = Seq.toList source` ;)

Comment: @Carsten For GitHub appending #L and line number to the URL will open the page to the line of code. I abuse it all the time.

Comment: hey thanks - so here is the *jumpy* [link](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/8f02ecb0b79947e67e6a0ef9c482d167baf17696/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L571)

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I didn't realise they were actually the same thing. Not sure of the point though, but at least I understand why they both work!

Comment: Perhaps part of the confusion is using the `List` module to work on sequences? In OO-world, anything in `List` *must* work on lists.
In FP-world, the `List` module is basically just a namespace, and so *any* function could be put in that namespace. We could even do something
silly such as define a `List.strToBool` function that had nothing to do with lists whatsoever!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both `List.ofSeq` and `Seq.toList` have type `'a seq -> 'a list` and indeed `List.ofSeq` is defined as

```
let ofSeq source = Seq.toList source
```

(defined in the [`Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List` module](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/8f02ecb0b79947e67e6a0ef9c482d167baf17696/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L571))

so indeed they are just the same.

---

As you get a list (which - unlike a `seq` - is a strict structure in F#) all the elements of the sequence are evaluated to populate the list in memory - that's why you can use both functions to force the iteration of all the values.